# AWS IAM control of a group of EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

We are using IAM permissions for groups and users with great success for S3, SQS, Redshift, etc.  The IAM for S3 in particular gives lovely level of details by path and bucket.

I am bumping into some head scratching when it comes to EC2 permissions.

How do I create a permission that allows an IAM user to:

- create up to *n* instances
- do whatever he/she wants on those instances **only** (terminate / stop / describe)

...and makes it impossible for him/her to affect our other instances (change termination / terminate / etc.) ?

I've been trying Conditions on tag (`"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/purpose": "test"}}`), but that means that all of our tools need to be modified to add that tag at creation time.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the number of instances an IAM user can create is not possible (unfortunately). All you have is a limit on the number of instances in the entire account.

Limiting permissions to specific instances is possible, but you have to specify the permissions for each instance-ID, using this format:

```
arn:aws:ec2:region:account:instance/instance-id
```

More information is available here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html